# Delete an instance before saving a new one (Django model save method)

Tags: django, django-models

I want to limit my model's records to a maximum of 10 rows per user (the model has a foreign key to user model). What is the best practice for that?

I thought about overriding save method, perform a check, and delete before saving:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
 if MyModel.objects.filter(user=self.user).count() >= 10:
     oldest_record =         MyModel.objects.filter(user=self.user).order_by('created_at').first()
 oldest_record.delete()
 super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I wonder if it is a good solution, if it's better (and what's the way to do it) to enforce that at database level, and potential problems when same user saves two instances at the same time (though very unlikely). Any experiences with something similar?

Comment: You can enforce this at the database, but it will cause more pain than gain.

Comment: I'm using Postgres, would a check constraint be valid? Could you argument your answer, please? I'd give as valid answer any good information about such practice and if it's not viable then that's how it is! @willeM_VanOnsem

Comment: use a `UniqueConstraint` on `user_id` and `F('pk') % 10`, but then you thus move the logic to picking a good primary key, which is quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve efficiency by using `user_id` instead of `user`, since it prevents fetching the user.

We can also obtain all items in one fetch, and thus prevent certain race conditions:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance._state.adding:
        items = (
            MyModel.objects.filter(user_id=self.user_id)
            .order_by('created_at')
            .only('pk')[9:]
        )
        if items:
            MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in={item.pk for item in items}).delete()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But overriding `.save()` methods, signals, etc. can all be circumvented by bulk operations (like bulk create).

> If it's better (and what's the way to do it) to enforce that at database level.

You *can* enforce this at the database level with a `UniqueConstraint` that makes the combination of the `user_id` and the primary key modulo ten unique. In that case, the logic moves to picking a good primary key.

So that means that for a user, we can assign it for example items with primary keys `51`, `26`, `32`, etc., but not again `31`, since `…1` is already "picked".

Probably it is better to periodically run a management commmand to clean up the old records, and at the front end always limit the number of `MyModel`s for a user to ten. This is probably quite robust.